# How to find an input using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to submit this form by clicking with selenium on the following input:

```
<div align="center">
 <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Aceptar">
</div>
```

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Aceptar']").click()
```

I also tried with the class name "boton" but doesn't work,

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "does not work"?  Is there an error? Does anything happen?

Comment: I mean nothing happened, and trying the answer below i got  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='Aceptar']"}

Comment: Try to [wait for element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: Check your DOM tree if there any `iframe` above the input element?

Comment: I have an implicitly_wait(20) @JaSON

Comment: There is an iframe with name="busqueda", and my target form is inside of the frame @KunduK

Comment: I have added an answer hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the `input` element you need to switch to `iframe` first.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce  `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"busqueda")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@value='Aceptar'][@class='boton']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

Update

`Input element` present inside nested iframes.Inorder to access you need to switch to nested `iframes`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.iframeTGR")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"busqueda")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@value='Aceptar'][@class='boton']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it help me a lot. still not working (TimeoutException) but now I know that I need to search on the iframe.

Comment: in fact, the input I need to access is in an iframe within another iframe, here is the resume of  html code <iframe class="iframeTGR">
#document
  <html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
   <iframe name="busqueda" id="id_busqueda">
 #document
 <html>
 <head>..</head>
 <body>
  # here its my input
 </body>
   </iframe>
</iframe>

Comment: @fukurowl : I have updated the answer for `nested iframes`.Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript executor to do it.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Aceptar']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Answer (score 0):

utilize `execute_script` in order to set the value attribute of an input field. check out the following code block:

```
input_field= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Aceptar']")

driver.execute_script("[0].click();",input_field)
```